# When are Spark RDD blocks created and destroyed/removed?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

There's a column called `RDD` blocks in the Spark UI in executors tab. One observation made is that the number of `RDD` blocks keeps increasing for a particular streaming job where messages are streamed from Kafka.

Certain executors were removed automatically and application slows down after long run with a large number of `RDD` blocks. `DStreams` and `RDDs` are not persisted manually anywhere.

It would be a great help if someone explains when these blocks are created and on what basis are the blocks being removed (are there any parameters that need to be modified?).

Comment: Looks like a possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067919/can-anyone-explain-about-rdd-blocks-in-executors

Comment: The above observation (Increase in executors' memory usage and OutOfMemory killed the executors) was found on Spark 1.6 and when the same task was run in Spark 2.2, no such issues were found (executors' memory consumed increases upto a certain level and was stable further).

Answer (score 5):

Good explanation of Spark UI is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41683142/8442366). RDD blocks can represent cached RDD partitions, intermediate shuffle outputs, broadcasts, etc. Check out BlockManager section of this [book](https://books.japila.pl/apache-spark-internals/apache-spark-internals/storage/BlockManager.html).